# Do Polar Bears drop loot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just updated my Minecraft to 1.10.2, and I tried to kill a Polar Bear but it didn't drop any loot(except exp).

Is this normal, or I was just unlucky? Also, if there are Polar Bears around, and I kill one of them, will the other bears hurt me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A polar bear will drop 0 to 2 raw fish 75% of the time, and 0 to 2 raw salmon 25% of the time. [Source.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Polar_Bear#Drops)

Comment: Thank you! I was checking wikia, but I couldn't find anything there. Also, I will accept your answer, for some reason, there is a time limit.

Comment: Minecraft gamepedia is always updated before wikia.

Comment: @r3pear The time limit is to encourage multiple answers. Stack Exchange sites work best when questions get multiple answers, and the best answers get voted to the top. If you immediately accept the first answer, no one has a chance to give a better answer.

Comment: @mouseas Then add a question. I might your question either, if it's better.

Comment: @mouseas Usually I agree but for a linear answer like this.. why wait..

Comment: Guys, chill. r3pear seemed confused as to why he had to wait to accept an answer. I saw he was a new-ish user, so I commented to explain the reasoning behind it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.10.2 Polar Bears **will not** attack when their friend is killed/hit. Also they won't attack you when you hit them.

It will drop raw fish (75% of the time) **OR** raw salmon (25%), never both, not even with looting.